# What will be expectation of brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I was solving a linear SDE and there I got the solution in this form
$X_t = X_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t} +  \theta\,\mu\,e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t}\int_0^t e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds$.
I was trying to find its mean. Since $\mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma W_t})=e^{\frac{\sigma^2~ t}{2}}$, So I got $ \mathbb{E}(X_t) = X_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2  t} +  \theta\,\mu\,e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2  t}\int_0^t \mathbb{E}\left\{e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds\right\}=X_0 e^{-\theta t}  +  \theta\mu\,e^{-\theta t} \int_0^t \mathbb{E}\left\{e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds\right\}=X_0 e^{-\theta t}  +  \theta\mu\,e^{-\theta t} \int_0^t e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s} \mathbb{E}\left(e^{- \sigma W_s}\right) ds$.

I stuck at $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{- \sigma W_s}\right)$. Kindly tell me what will be its expectation. Also, I am not sure whether my steps are right or wrong? Please help me.

Comment: $\mathbb E(e^{-\sigma W_s})=e^{\sigma^{2} s /2}$.

Comment: I actually guessed that. Can you please tell me whether my steps are correct?

Comment: You have made a mistake. You have written $EXY=EX EY$ for  the second term without independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the expectation of $ \int_0^t e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds$.

Comment: What you need is actually the expectation of $e^{\sigma W_t}$ **multiplied by this integral**.

Comment: I did not get you. Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

We will evaluate each term

$$X_t = X_0 e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t} +  \theta\,\mu\,e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t}\int_0^t e^{(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) s - \sigma W_s} ds.$$

We have

$$E[e^{-(\theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) t + \sigma W_t}]=exp(-\theta t)$$

and

$$E[e^{\sigma(W_{t}-W_{s})}]=exp(\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}(t-s)).$$

So

$$E[X_{t}]=X_{0}exp(-\theta_{t})+\theta\mu\int_{0}^{t}exp(-\theta(t-s))ds.$$